# Save 2 fits files with 3 headers astropy or pyfits

Tags: python, astropy, pyfits

I am trying to make a fits file with two images inside of it, and i want to give them both a header. There should also be a basic header for the both of them. What I have found until now is this, but I don't know how to add the headers properly. Variables are headermain, header1, header2, data1, data2. I want it to have this structure.

```
Filename: test.fits
No.    Name         Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
0    PRIMARY     PrimaryHDU     828   ()              
1    name1  ImageHDU        52   (1024, 900)   float32   
2    name2  ImageHDU        52   (1024, 900)   float32
```

I currently have this, but I can't find how to add headers.

```
new_hdul = pyfits.HDUList()
new_hdul.append(pyfits.ImageHDU(data1)
new_hdul.append(pyfits.ImageHDU(data2)

new_hdul.writeto('test.fits', clobber=True)
```

Comment: new_hdul.append(pyfits.ImageHDU(data1,header)

Comment: What you'r asking is how to create a multi-extension FITS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [astropy documentation on ImageHDU](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/images.html) you can pass the header as keyword to the `ImageHDU`:

```
from astropy.io import fits

new_hdul = fits.HDUList()
new_hdul.append(fits.PrimaryHDU(header=headermain))
new_hdul.append(fits.ImageHDU(data1, header=header1, name='name1'))
new_hdul.append(fits.ImageHDU(data2, header=header2, name='name2'))

new_hdul.writeto('test.fits', clobber=True)
```

Comment: and where would i put mainheader? in the HDUList?

Comment: Thats great! I missed the header= and just tried to put in the header... 
Also can I also give them a name?

Comment: I've included the `name` parameter and the Primary Header in the answer. :)

Comment: It does not accept my header objects. I should be able to put these in right? 'headermain = pyfits.getheader(list1[i],0)'

Comment: It gives "header must be a Header object"

Comment: Could you open another question for that? Converting something to a `pyfits.Header()` or `astropy.io.fits.Header()` has nothing do with your original question here. :)

Comment: Good point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459463/copy-header-into-new-file-astropy