# Copy header into new file astropy

Tags: astropy, pyfits

I have this script that makes a file with multiple extensions, but I would like to add headers from the old files to the extensions.

```
new_hdul = fits.HDUList()
new_hdul.append(fits.PrimaryHDU(header=headermain))
new_hdul.append(fits.ImageHDU(nod1, header=header1, name='Chop1')) 
new_hdul.append(fits.ImageHDU(nod2, header=header2, name='Chop2'))
new_hdul.append(fits.ImageHDU(diff1, name='Dif'))
```

Now I have tried:

```
headermain = fits.getheader(file,0)
```

and

```
headermain = fits.open(file).header.copy()
```

But both give me errors saying that

> ValueError: header must be a Header object

How can I fix this?

```
headermain = fits.getheader(file,0)
print(headermain)
```

see http://pastebin.com/JXki7EPV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally getting the header as Header object from a file isn't complicated. You `astropy.io.fits.open()` the file and extract the Header from the PrimaryHDU with:

```
from astropy.io import fits

filename = 'test.fits'

with fits.open(filename) as hdus:
    headermain = hdus[0].header
```

or with `getheader`:

```
headermain = fits.getheader(filename) # Defaults to primary header!
```

and the result will be a `fits.Header`-object that you can use during writing.

But if your file is not a valid FITS file there might be problems. If this doesn't work could you edit your question and show the output of any of these two functions?

```
print(headermain)
```

Comment: I tried both methods and both give the same error. I pasted the output of the headermain.

Comment: @Coolcrab - If you found the Error yourself you can answer your own question. :)

Comment: I was mixing pyfits and astropy.fits, so the method described above and by you is correct when not doing that.

Comment: oh, I never would have guessed that but in retrospect it's obvious. General advice: Don't use `pyfits` if you have `astropy`. See the [important Note on the Pyfits-Homepage](http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyfits)